# Unwanted whitespace below KeyboardAwareFlatList in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am using a `KeyboardAwareFlatList` in React Native, but there appears to be a bug with it. When I go from a screen with bottom tabs to a screen where I have removed bottom tabs I occasionally see [this](https://imgur.com/a/JTRAGvm) at the bottom.

I say occasionally because sometimes it is there, but then disappears if I go back and return to the screen. If I wait long enough on the screen it goes away too. It's pretty annoying, and I can't figure out what the issue is. Does anyone know a fix?

Here is my code:

```
<KeyboardAwareFlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 2,
  }}
  keyboardOpeningTime={0.25}
  data={messages}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View
      key={index}
      style={[
        styles.message,
        msg.sender === 'user' ? styles.userMessage : styles.botMessage,
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.messageText}>{msg.message}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.messageTimestamp}>
        {new Date(msg.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString()}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )}
  ListFooterComponent={
    <MessageInputBar
      message={message}
      setMessage={setMessage}
      handleSend={handleSend}
    />
  }
/>

    const MessageInputBar = ({message, setMessage, handleSend}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.messageInput}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Type your message here"
        value={message}
        onChangeText={text => setMessage(text)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton} onPress={handleSend}>
        <Text style={styles.sendButtonText}>Send</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```